# Caching in Python for computationally intensive applications

Tags: scale

I am working on a machine learning project which involve processing a **very** large dataset. The dataset can be thought of a list of objects, each object holds 100 MB of data. Loading all the objects at once into memory slows down the processing. My current work around is to load each object individually and process it and save the processing outcome to disk. This process is repeated for each layer of processing the objects undergo.

I was wondering if python has a caching workaround, where basically it cache data to disk and load them only when they are needed for processing?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), with it data can be cached per function to different back-ends, with different expirations, and different keys.

You can also use [Memoize Decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize). It caches a function's return value each time it is called. If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned (not re-evaluated).

From Python 3.2 you can use the decorator [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from the functools library. It's a Last Recently Used cache, so there is no expiration time for the items in it, but as a fast hack it's very useful.

You can also use [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/). Transparent disk-caching of the output values and lazy re-evaluation (memoize pattern), easy simple parallel computing logging and tracing of the execution

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if python has a caching workaround, where basically it
>   cache data to disk and load them only when they are needed for
>   processing?

Isn't that kind of "caching" is what you already do? You load subsets one by one and process them independently. (I hope you don't do this manually)

You are lucky that you don't *need* to load all the datasets simultaneously.